# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.request(Lshadow/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMethod;)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, reactor-netty

getting exception when using azure function refernce having cosmos db in other service :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.request(Lshadow/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMethod;)Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient$RequestSender;
at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.ReactorNettyClient.send(ReactorNettyClient.java:132)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/381)?

Try adding `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_JAVA_LOAD_APP_LIBS` to your [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal). E.g. via `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "FUNCTION_APP_STORAGE_CONN_STR_PLACEHOLDER_VALUE",

    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_JAVA_LOAD_APP_LIBS": 1,


    "MY_SETTING_1": "VAL1"
    ...
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {...}
}
```